# I can't get iframe elements in Chrome

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-chrome

I'm trying to get an element in an iframe with contentWindow.document (or contentDocument).

I was able to get information without problems with FireFox and Chrome version 99 or earlier, but suddenly I can not get information with Chrome version 100 or later.

Also, I'm not sure if it's related, but this phenomenon occurred only in the JS described on the fixed page of Wordpress, and did not occur in the html page that is not Wordpress.

The outline of the source is as follows.

```
<iframe src="/form/terms/sample.html" width="100%" height="500px" frameborder="0" id="iframe"></iframe>
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
    var iframe_doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    console.log(iframe_doc);
}
</script>
```

The result is below, the body element is empty.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

The version of Wordpress is 5.7.6.

Do you know the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Tested on Firefox v102, got following error: `Uncaught DOMException: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object`

The err happens if you process it on the website starts load.

First add a `<meta>` tag in `<head>`:

```html
<meta name="referer" content="access-control-allow-origin"/>
```

Then edit the JavaScript code:

```js
(function() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById("iframe");
    var iframe_doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    console.log(iframe_doc);
})();
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Thank you for the advice.

I changed JS by putting <meta> in <head>, but the result did not change.

Also, you are trying to get information from the same origin, but is there a case where it is not the same origin because it is a Wordpress page?

iframe URL:
https://sample.jp/form/terms/sample.html

Reference URL:
https://sample.jp/ref_page

Comment: Hmm I can't connect to sample.jp....

Comment: I'm sorry, this URL is given as an example, so it doesn't actually exist. (In any case, if you try to get from a different domain, you will get a cross-domain error)

If you can verify it, please set up each file on the same server you have and try it.